# Create a filled pixmap for box2d fixture

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I'm trying to make a pixmap that fills in a Box2D fixture. It would be kind of like a fill bucket. I've done this before, but I want it to work on rectangles and other polygons. Is there an algorithm to do is, or will I need to write on myself? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried Pixmap#fillRectangle? http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Pixmap.html#fillRectangle-int-int-int-int-

Comment: Yes, but I'm unaware of how to get a proper width and height for a fixture.